# Flutter Enable/Disable Button based on TextFormField content

Tags: button, keyboard, flutter, textfield, flutter-layout

How can I activate/deactivate a button based on the content of a TextFormField?

I want to make sure a user can only press Button X if the TextFormField has 10 entered numbers (if it's a mobile number).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way would be to set the autovalidate property of our TextFormField to `true`. This will automatically detect for changes on our TextFormField widget. We can then try to check if our TextFormField's value has a String length of 10 characters on the validator property . After that we can call setState to enable or disable our button (I use FlatButton in this example).

```
bool _btnEnabled = false;

...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){

  ...

  TextFormField(

    ...
    autovalidate: true,
    validator: (String txt){
      if (txt.length == 10){
        setState((){
          _btnEnabled = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState((){
          _btnEnabled = false;
        });
      }
    }

    ...

  FlatButton(
    onPressed: _btnEnabled == true ? yourCallback : null,
    child: ...
```

Comment: how do we validate multiple text fields using this approach that after every field is validated, the button gets enabled?

Answer (score 24):

The state of the widget can be updated in the Form's onChanged callback which is called whenever any of the form fields' value changes. There you can use a form key to validate the form and set a flag to enable/disable the button. This solution allows you to scale to disable buttons in forms with multiple fields. For example,

```
/// Key used to reference the form.
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

...

Form(
  key: _formKey,
  onChanged: () => setState(() => _enableBtn = _formKey.currentState.validate()),
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        validator: (value) => value.length < 10 ?
          'Number must be at least 10 digits' : // return an error message
          null,
        ...
      ),
    ],
  ),
)

...

FlatButton(
  onPressed: _enableBtn ?
    () => _doSomething() :
    null, // setting onPressed to null disables the button.
  ...
```

Comment: if there are other fields in the form, the other fields will also be validated at the same time

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer seems to not work using the latest Flutter v1.7.8 (stable), it gives me the following error:

This TestForm widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets

The working version looks like the following:

```
...
autovalidate: true,
validator: (String txt){
      bool isValid = txt.length == 10;
      if (isValid != _btnEnabled) {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          setState(() {
            _btnEnabled = txt.length == 10;
          });
        });
      } 
}

...
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use Flutter [Reactive Forms](https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms). It's a model-driven approach to handling Forms inputs and validations, heavily inspired in Angular's Reactive Forms.

It's a very simple to use libray and in the documentation there is a section that explains how to Enable/Disable Submit button based on the validity of the entire form, not just a field.

Comment: Thanks - your answer helped me a lot.
Reactive Forms seems fantastic, I'm giving it a try.
It looks very similar to Angular's reactive forms.
The best part (for me) is that they support async validators, which is a feature I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method .

```
  bool isEnable = false;

void validateButton() {
    bool isValid = true;

    isValid = userEmail.isNotEmpty &&
        userPassword.isNotEmpty &&
        validateEmail(userEmail) &&
        userPassword.length >= 8;

    setState(() {
      isEnable = isValid;
    });
  }
```

now in your Textfield onChanged method you have to call this function

like This

```
onChanged: (email) {
                        userEmail = email;
                        setState(() {});
                        validateButton();
                      },
```

and in your Login Button

```
isEnable?ActiveButton():DisableButton()
```

Answer (score -1):

Get error "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." with accepted answer. Just add Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then(....) as a trick solution, it's working on flutter 1.12.13

```
TextFormField(

...
autovalidate: true,
validator: (String txt){
  if (txt.length == 10){
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_){
    setState((){
      _btnEnabled = true;
    });
  });
  } else {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_){
    setState((){
      _btnEnabled = false;
    });
  });
  }
}
....
```